# Why stack function not accepting a string of characters?

Tags: c, string, stack, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create a push function in stack that accepts a string of character and store each characters in separate nodes, but when I ran the program and enter a string it only stores the first letter. Below is the code that was used to for the function:

```
void push(char *word){
struct stack *newNode = malloc(sizeof(char *));
if(newNode == NULL){
    printf("unable to push to stack");
}else{
    strcpy(newNode -> word,word);
    newNode -> next = head;
    head = newNode;
    }
    printf("Inserted in stack\n");
}

int main(){
int choice;
char str[100];

printf("Enter a string: ");
gets(str);

while(1)
{
    printf("******** Menu ********\n");
    printf(" 1. Push\n 2. Display\n 3. Exit\n");
    printf("Enter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1:
            push(str);
            break;
        case 2:
            display();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\nProgram Exited\n");
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Incorrect selection!\n");
    }
void display(){

struct stack* newNode;
if(head == NULL){
    printf("\nStack is Empty!!!\n");
}else{
    newNode = head;
    while(newNode != NULL){
        printf("%c--->", newNode -> word);
        newNode = newNode -> next;
    }
  }
}

}
```

Comment: Why are you only allocating enough space for `sizeof(char *)`? It should be `malloc(sizeof(struct stack))`. `strcpy` requires that the destination buffer be allocated and large enough to fit the string. `newNode->word` has not even been allocated. It is only printing a character because "%c" in printf means print a character which shouldnt even be printing the correct character. Sorry but this needs too many changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of problems here, the first being that it's not the full set of code.  You are missing:

- Include of header files for C library functions you are using
- The definition of *struct stack*
- The declaration of the variable *head*
- A prototype for the function *display()*, as it is called before it is defined

In addition, you have the following code errors:

- malloc of *char** rather than the correct size for a node in the linked list, i.e. *struct stack*
- printf format %c, a single character, when you want to print the string stored in the node, which would be %s

And finally, you are using the following bad practices:

- *gets()* is deprecated and dangerous (and the compiler will even tell you as much in its warning); use *fgets()* instead
- Not checking the return value of *scanf()* to handle the case where the user enters something other than a number
- The memory you allocated with *malloc()* is never freed anywhere

However, filling in the missing pieces and correcting the errors I mentioned, as well as formatting the code for readability, I am able to run it and verify that the *push()* function does manage to insert into the head of the linked list correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRING_MAX 100

struct stack
{
    char word[STRING_MAX];
    struct stack *next;
};

struct stack *head = NULL;

void display();

void push(char *word)
{
    struct stack *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("unable to push to stack\n");
    }
    else
    {
        strcpy(newNode -> word,word);
        newNode -> next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    printf("Inserted in stack\n");
}

int main()
{
    int choice;
    char str[STRING_MAX];

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    gets(str);

    while(1)
    {
        printf("******** Menu ********\n");
        printf(" 1. Push\n 2. Display\n 3. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch(choice)
        {
            case 1:
                push(str);
                break;
            case 2:
                display();
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("\nProgram Exited\n");
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Incorrect selection!\n");
                break;
        }
    }
    
    display();
    
    return 0;
}

void display()
{
    struct stack* newNode;
    if(head == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nStack is Empty!!!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        newNode = head;
        while(newNode != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s--->", newNode -> word);
            newNode = newNode -> next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[You can run the corrected code here.](https://onlinegdb.com/Bklh2D9SLD)

Comment: Thanks mate, function works fine now.
Appreciate your response and help!

Comment: I would like to add the pop function to this code to make a complete stack program. I've implemented the function, but it pops the entire string instead of one character at a time. Any suggestions for the pop function based on the code above?

Comment: For a typical stack implementation, the result of pop is exactly what was inserted by push.  Since your push function adds a node containing a string, it makes perfect sense that pop would give back that same string and not one character at a time from the pushed string.  In other words, you don't push character by character, so why would you expect to pop character by character?  That's a very strange stack implementation.